# Custom logging to app insights from .net core

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core

I'm using App Insights in a .net core web app and I can successfully see the telemetry data in the app insights logs. I would now like to be able to push up my own log events, but cannot seem to get it to work (i.e. my custom log events do not appear in app insights). My code is as follows:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices);
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Startup>();

    logger.LogInformation("I am a log event");
```

I've also tried setting the log level explicitly like:

```
loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices, LogLevel.Debug);
```

But I never see the text "I am a log event" in app insights.

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this?

Comment: This approach is nowadays obsolete. Please see [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#frequently-asked-questions)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. You need to add an Application Insights log capture module for that. Select the appropriate package - one of:

   - Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener (to capture
     System.Diagnostics.Trace calls)
   - Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.EventSourceListener (to capture
     EventSource events)
   - Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.EtwListener (to
     capture ETW events)
   - Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget
   - Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Log4NetAppender

Documentation section: [Explore .NET trace logs in Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-trace-logs)

2. Also, you may use `TelemetryClient` directly. It has more options, not only `TrackTrace` that is used by loggers.

```
//TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient();
...
telemetryClient.TrackEvent("<EventName>");
telemetryClient.TrackMetric("<metric name>", 1);
telemetryClient.TrackTrace("message", SeverityLevel.Information);
```

Documentation section: [Application Insights API for custom events and metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-trace-logs)

For the live example, you may look into [feature test](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/blob/master/test/EmptyApp.FunctionalTests/Startup.cs) int `ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore` repo.

Comment: Can application insight create different columns for logs? Like I want to send logs like { azure function 1,started, time, GUID, filename, containername, etc }. This will be one row of logs. So my application insights create columns according to it.

Comment: I suppose there is recommendation from microsoft to not new up the telemetryclient object rather pass it as a dependency. Which can be done using services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry() in configure service method